# MySQL change data set with table JOIN .. Is what I am asking possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is a complicated question, so please bear with me.  I am using 3 different tables to make 1 result set.  They are as follows:

```
customer_address_entity
    entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | increment_id | parent_id | create_at | update_at | is_active

customer_entity_int
    value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id | value


customer_address_entity_varchar
    value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | entity_id | value
```

Ok, so now you have the structure, here is my SQL call I have built so far:

```
SELECT CAE.entity_id, 
       CEI.value AS default_entity_id, 
       CAEV.attribute_id, 
       CAEV.value 
FROM   customer_address_entity AS CAE 
       JOIN customer_entity_int AS CEI 
         ON CEI.entity_id = CAE.parent_id 
            AND CEI.attribute_id = '13' 
       JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS CAEV 
         ON CAEV.entity_id = CAE.entity_id 
WHERE  CAE.parent_id = '2328' 
       AND CAE.is_active = 1
```

This outputs the following example dataset:

```
 ID     default  att   value

'1567', '1567', '19', 'John'
'1567', '1567', '21', 'Doe'
'1567', '1567', '23', 'Johns Company'
'1567', '1567', '25', 'Johns City'
'1567', '1567', '26', 'Johns Country'
'1567', '1567', '27', 'Johns State'
'1567', '1567', '29', 'Johns Zip Code'
'1567', '1567', '30', 'Johns Phone'
'1567', '1567', '31', 'Johns Fax'
'1568', '1567', '19', 'Jane'
'1568', '1567', '21', 'Doe'
'1568', '1567', '23', 'Janes Company'
'1568', '1567', '25', 'Janes City'
'1568', '1567', '26', 'Janes Country'
'1568', '1567', '27', 'Janes State'
'1568', '1567', '29', 'Janes Zip'
'1568', '1567', '30', 'Janes Phone'
'1568', '1567', '31', 'Janes Fax'
'1569', '1567', '19', 'Frank'
'1569', '1567', '21', 'Frunz'
'1569', '1567', '23', 'Franks Company'
'1569', '1567', '25', 'Franks City'
'1569', '1567', '26', 'Franks Country'
'1569', '1567', '27', 'Franks State'
'1569', '1567', '29', 'Franks Zip'
'1569', '1567', '30', 'Franks Phone'
'1569', '1567', '31', 'Franks Fax'
```

The final part of this code, I would like to create X number (in this case 3) of ROWS based on the number `UNIQUE` `entity_id` (Column 1 in returned data set ie .1567,1568 and 1569).  The intended end result being:

```
'1567', '1567', 'John', 'Doe', 'Johns Company', 'Johns City', 'Johns State', 'Johns Zip Code', 'Johns Phone', 'Johns Fax'
'1568', '1567', 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Janes Company', ...  etc
'1569', '1567', 'Frank', 'Franz', 'Franks Comapny', ...   etc
```

Is this even possible?

**EDIT** Thanks to Gordon Linoff --  The answer is elegant and simple!  I threw in a few edits of my own, but will be accepting Gordons answer and voting it up.  Here are the edits I made, which work beautifully!!

```
select entity_id,
   if(entity_id = default_entity_id, 'true', 'false') as default_entity,
   max(case when attr = '19' then `value` end) as `FirstName`,
   max(case when attr = '21' then `value` end) as `LastName`,
   max(case when attr = '23' then `value` end) as `CompanyName`,
   max(case when attr = '25' then `value` end) as `City`,
   max(case when attr = '27' then `value` end) as `State`,
   max(case when attr = '29' then `value` end) as `ZipCode`,
   max(case when attr = '30' then `value` end) as `PhoneNumber`,
   max(case when attr = '31' then `value` end) as `Fax`

from (SELECT CAE.entity_id, CEI.value AS default_entity_id, CAEV.attribute_id AS attr, CAEV.value 
  FROM   customer_address_entity CAE 
         JOIN customer_entity_int CEI 
           ON CEI.entity_id = CAE.parent_id 
              AND CEI.attribute_id = '13' 
         JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar CAEV 
           ON CAEV.entity_id = CAE.entity_id 
  WHERE  CAE.parent_id = '2328' 
         AND CAE.is_active = 1
 ) as t
group by entity_id
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is transpose rows to columns; which is possible.

Comment: Do you know the values ahead of time?  Or are the number of values unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `group by`:

```
select entity_id,
       MAX(default) as default,
       max(case when att = '19' then value end) as FirstName,
       max(case when att = '21' then value end) as LastName,
       max(case when att = '23' then value end) as CompanyName,
       max(case when att = '25' then value end) as City,
       max(case when att = '27' then value end) as State,
       max(case when att = '29' then value end) as ZipCode,
       max(case when att = '30' then value end) as PhoneNumber,
       max(case when att = '31' then value end) as Fax
from (SELECT CAE.entity_id, CEI.value AS default_entity_id, CAEV.attribute_id, CAEV.value 
      FROM   customer_address_entity CAE 
             JOIN customer_entity_int CEI 
               ON CEI.entity_id = CAE.parent_id 
                  AND CEI.attribute_id = '13' 
             JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar CAEV 
               ON CAEV.entity_id = CAE.entity_id 
      WHERE  CAE.parent_id = '2328' 
             AND CAE.is_active = 1
     ) t
group by entity_id
```

This process is called *pivoting* and aggreagtion is one solution (some databases have a `pivot` keyword for this).    This assumes that each value appears only once per entity.  Also, if a value is not present, it will get the value NULL.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I edited your code and appended my question.  So simple, but powerful!  Love it!

Answer (score 0):

As [@Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203297/mysql-change-data-set-with-table-join-is-what-i-am-asking-possible/14204220#14204220) answer points out, this is what is known as a `PIVOT` but MySQL does not have that function.  In MySQL you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

You can hard-code the values if they are all known:

```
SELECT CAE.entity_id, 
    CEI.value AS default_entity_id,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 19 then CAEV.value else null end) FirstName,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 21 then CAEV.value else null end) LastName,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 23 then CAEV.value else null end) Company,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 25 then CAEV.value else null end) City,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 26 then CAEV.value else null end) Country,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 27 then CAEV.value else null end) State,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 29 then CAEV.value else null end) ZipCode,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 30 then CAEV.value else null end) Phone,
    MAX(case when CAEV.attribute_id = 31 then CAEV.value else null end) Fax
FROM   customer_address_entity AS CAE 
JOIN customer_entity_int AS CEI 
    ON CEI.entity_id = CAE.parent_id 
    AND CEI.attribute_id = '13' 
JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS CAEV 
    ON CAEV.entity_id = CAE.entity_id 
WHERE  CAE.parent_id = '2328' 
    AND CAE.is_active = 1 
GROUP BY CAE.entity_id, CEI.value;
```

Or you can use a prepared statement to implement dynamic sql. I would assume that you have a table that ties each attribute value to the name of the attribute:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when CAEV.attribute_id = ''',
      attribute_id,
      ''' then CAEV.value else null end) AS `',
      attribute_id, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM customer_address_entity_varchar;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT CAE.entity_id, 
                        CEI.value AS default_entity_id, ', @sql, '
                   FROM   customer_address_entity AS CAE 
                   JOIN customer_entity_int AS CEI 
                        ON CEI.entity_id = CAE.parent_id 
                        AND CEI.attribute_id = ''13' '
                    JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS CAEV 
                        ON CAEV.entity_id = CAE.entity_id 
                    WHERE  CAE.parent_id = ''2328''
                        AND CAE.is_active = 1 
                    GROUP BY CAE.entity_id, CEI.value');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```